# Calculating Rolling Sum with Condition in Scala DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame in Scala that looks like this:

```
+---+------+----------+-------+-----------+
|id |amount|date      |ndxdays|ndxdaysDate|
+---+------+----------+-------+-----------+
|1  |77    |2023-10-01|2      |2023-09-29 |
|1  |14    |2023-10-02|2      |2023-09-30 |
|1  |70    |2023-10-04|2      |2023-10-02 |
|1  |70    |2023-10-05|2      |2023-10-03 |
|1  |14    |2023-10-07|2      |2023-10-05 |
|2  |65    |2023-10-01|3      |2023-09-28 |
|2  |32    |2023-10-02|3      |2023-09-29 |
|2  |21    |2023-10-03|3      |2023-09-30 |
|2  |78    |2023-10-07|3      |2023-10-04 |
|3  |80    |2023-10-01|2      |2023-09-29 |
|3  |98    |2023-10-03|2      |2023-10-01 |
|3  |36    |2023-10-06|2      |2023-10-04 |
+---+------+----------+-------+-----------+
```

I need to calculate a rolling sum for each row, where the sum should backtrack and include the "amount" only from rows where current rows ndxDaysDate is less than the  row's date. In other words, I want to calculate the cumulative sum of "amount" up to the current date while respecting the ndxDaysDate condition.

##### Expected Output:

```
+---+------+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+
|id |amount|date      |ndxdays|ndxdaysDate|rollingsum |
+---+------+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+
|1  |77    |2023-10-01|2      |2023-09-29 |       77  |<-  Only 77 2023-10-01(date) > 2023-09-29(ndxdaysDate) for id 1
|1  |14    |2023-10-02|2      |2023-09-30 |       91  |<-  14 + 77 as  2023-10-02(date)  and 2023-10-01 (date) > 2023-09-30(ndxdaysDate) for id 1
|1  |70    |2023-10-04|2      |2023-10-02 |       70  |<-  Only 70 2023-10-04(date) > 2023-10-02(ndxdaysDate) for id 1
|1  |70    |2023-10-05|2      |2023-10-03 |       140 |<-  70 + 70 as  2023-10-05(date)  and 2023-10-04 (date) > 2023-10-03(ndxdaysDate) for id 1
|1  |14    |2023-10-07|2      |2023-10-05 |       14  |<-  Only 14 as  2023-10-07(date)   > 2023-10-05(ndxdaysDate) for id 1
|2  |65    |2023-10-01|3      |2023-09-28 |       65  |<-  Only 65 2023-10-01(date) > 2023-09-28(ndxdaysDate) for id 2
|2  |32    |2023-10-02|3      |2023-09-29 |       97  |<-  65+ 32 as  2023-10-02(date)  and 2023-10-01 (date) > 2023-09-29(ndxdaysDate) for id 2
|2  |21    |2023-10-03|3      |2023-09-30 |       118 |<-  65+ 32+ 21 as  2023-10-03,2023-10-02 and 2023-10-01 (date) > 2023-09-29(ndxdaysDate) for id 2
|2  |78    |2023-10-07|3      |2023-10-04 |       78  |<-  Only 78 2023-10-07(date) > 2023-10-04(ndxdaysDate) for id 2
|3  |80    |2023-10-01|2      |2023-09-29 |       80  |<-  Only 77 2023-10-01(date) > 2023-09-29(ndxdaysDate) for id 3
|3  |98    |2023-10-03|2      |2023-10-01 |       98  |<-  Only 98 2023-10-03(date) > 2023-10-01(ndxdaysDate) for id 3
|3  |36    |2023-10-06|2      |2023-10-04 |       36  |<-  Only 36 2023-10-06(date) > 2023-10-04(ndxdaysDate) for id 3
+---+------+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Provide your expected output.

Comment: @Kombajnzbożowy I have update question with expect output

Comment: you want code or sql answer ?

Comment: Abdennacer Lachiheb when you mean code? using data frame?

Answer (score 2):

Using SQL with a simple join:

```sql
SELECT main.*, sum(am.amount) as rollingsum
  FROM df as main
  LEFT JOIN df as am ON (am.id = main.id
                     AND main.ndxDaysDate < am.date
                     AND am.date <= main.date)
 GROUP BY main.id, main.amount, main.date, main.ndxdays, main.ndxDaysDate;

+---+----------+------+-------+-----------+----------+
|id |date      |amount|ndxDays|ndxDaysDate|rollingsum|
+---+----------+------+-------+-----------+----------+
|1  |2023-10-01|77    |2      |2023-09-29 |77        |
|1  |2023-10-02|14    |2      |2023-09-30 |91        |
|1  |2023-10-04|70    |2      |2023-10-02 |70        |
|1  |2023-10-05|70    |2      |2023-10-03 |140       |
|1  |2023-10-07|14    |2      |2023-10-05 |14        |
|2  |2023-10-01|65    |3      |2023-09-28 |65        |
|2  |2023-10-02|32    |3      |2023-09-29 |97        |
|2  |2023-10-03|21    |3      |2023-09-30 |118       |
|2  |2023-10-07|78    |3      |2023-10-04 |78        |
|3  |2023-10-01|80    |2      |2023-09-29 |80        |
|3  |2023-10-03|98    |2      |2023-10-01 |98        |
|3  |2023-10-06|36    |2      |2023-10-04 |36        |
+---+----------+------+-------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't thought of solving this via simple join. I thinking from the perspective of using Window and custom UDF.  I will check and confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

Since Spark 3.0, you can do it using a window as follows:

- collect all the date and amount from previous rows in an array with `collect_set` and a window
- drop all the dates that are before `ndxDaysDate` using `filter`
- sum amounts of remaining elements of the array using `aggregate`

It gives you the following scala code, assuming you call your input dataframe `df`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{aggregate, col, collect_set, filter, lit, struct}

val window = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date")

val result = df
  .withColumn(
   "rollingsum",
    aggregate(
      filter(
        collect_set(struct("date", "amount")).over(window), // collect date and amount of all previous rows
        x => x.getField("date") > col("ndxdaysDate") // filter them by using current row's ndxdaysDate column
      ),
      lit(0),
      (acc, elem) => acc + elem.getField("amount") // sum amounts of all the remaining elements in the array
    )
  )
```

From Spark 1.6 to Spark 2.4, you can replace `aggregate` and `filter` calls with an udf, as follows:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, collect_set, struct, udf}

def filteredSum(dateAndAmounts: List[(LocalDate, Int)], ndxdaysDate: LocalDate): Int = {
  dateAndAmounts.filter(_._1.isAfter(ndxdaysDate)).map(_._2).sum
}

val filtered_sum = udf(filteredSum _)

val window = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date")

val result = df
  .withColumn("rollingSum", filtered_sum(
    collect_set(struct("date", "amount")).over(window), 
    col("ndxdaysDate"))
  )
```

Comment: Thanks, @Vincent Doba , this seems to be the correct solution, unfortunately, our spark version 2.4.4

Comment: @akreddy.21 I added the udf version for spark from version 1.6 to version 2.4